# How to make a popup like the Emoji Button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

There is this script that someone made that you can click a button and it will open a little popup window and an emoji keyboard will show. Then you can click away and it'll close. How can I make something like that, but instead of an emoji keyboard showing up, it's a `.html` page

Example **index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Emoji Test</title>
  <script src="emoji-button.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var picker = new EmojiButton();
      var button = document.querySelector('#emoji-button');
      button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        picker.showPicker(button);
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Emoji Button</h1>
  <button id="emoji-button"></button>
</body>

</html>
```

Download link - emoji-button.min.js:

```
https://github.com/joeattardi/emoji-button/releases/download/v2.4.0/emoji-button.min.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>popup</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#largeModal">&#128540;</button>

  <div id="largeModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Large Modal</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Add the <code>.modal-lg</code> class on <code>.modal-dialog</code> to create this large modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>popup</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#largeModal">&#128540;</button>

  <div id="largeModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Large Modal</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Add the <code>.modal-lg</code> class on <code>.modal-dialog</code> to create this large modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```